# Как передеать в метод значение переменной, а не ссылку в памяти

Tags: c#

Я в цикле генерирую карту состоящий из кнопок, каждой из них надо создать уникальный Listener.
Генератор карты:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        GameObject button = Instane(/* some settings */);
        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { Function(y, x); });
    }
}
```

Так получается что все Listeners имеют ссылку на область в памяти, то есть на x и y и все они будут возвращать 3, 5 , так как после завершения цикла они равны 3, 5 и не удаляются так как в Listener все еще есть ссылка на x и y. Так вот, как сделать так, чтоб в метод передавалась не ссылка на объект в памяти, а именно значение, чтоб это было похоже на это new int[] { 1, 2 } , а не это new int[] { &x , &y }?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замкнитесь локальные переменные внутри цикла:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        GameObject button = Instane(/* some settings */);
        int x1 = x, y1 = y;
        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { Function(y1, x1); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Обогнал однако =) Может стоит добавить пару слов почему так происходит?

Comment: Да, сработало, а можно объяснить почему так работает?

Comment: @NeulovimFox когда вы передаете в лямбду (анонимный делегат) локальные переменные образуется, так называемое, замыкание. В итоге в исходном коде у вас локальная переменная, а в исполняемом служебный объект. Вообще эта тема довольно обширная, не для комментария.

Comment: Можно тогда скинуть какую нибудь статейку на этот счет?

Comment: @NeulovimFox ну навскидку нагуглилось https://rsdn.org/article/csharp/Closure_in_Csharp.xml и https://itvdn.com/ru/blog/article/closing-in-csharp В любом случае стоит ориентироваться на спецификацию языка, т.к. конкретная реализация и поведение не гарантированы и могут меняться в будущих версиях.

Comment: Большое спасибо)